# AttributeError: 'CausalModel' object has no attribute 'causal_estimator' (Causal Inference and Discovery in Python)

Tags: python, causality

I tried to run the notebook provided along with the book ([Causal Inference and Discovery in Python - Chapter 10](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Causal-Inference-and-Discovery-in-Python/blob/main/Chapter_10.ipynb). When I run this specific block

```
# Compute predictions
effect_pred = model.causal_estimator.effect(earnings_interaction_test.drop(['true_effect', 'took_a_course'], axis=1))

# Get the true effect
effect_true = earnings_interaction_test['true_effect'].values
```

I got an error:
AttributeError: 'CausalModel' object has no attribute 'causal_estimator'

The book states that it uses DoWhy 0.8 and I am currently using DoWhy 0.10.1 (I want to keep my learning experience up-to-date) so I think the library must have changed the way to make prediction on test dataset with a model. The trouble is, I cannot find what the change is.

I have tried searching Dowhy's [documentation](https://www.pywhy.org/dowhy/v0.10.1/index.html) and [Github page](https://github.com/py-why/dowhy) but, unfortunately, my limited knowledge of coding and causal inference denied me the answer.

Much appreciate your help!

Comment: The 0.8 docs do not seem to mention a `CausalModel.causal_estimator` method either, so you probably made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @mkrieger1 thanks for your reply. I simply took the code provided by the author of the book from its Github repo and I ran the notebook step-by-step. If the 0.8 doc did not have `CausalModel.causal_estimator`, does that mean the code provided by the author is somehow erroneous?

Comment: If you got the code from github, perhaps you can raise an issue?